# Height of Current Font in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

In Word, I want to insert a box or an image whose height is identical to a current font height. Different fonts have different heights—Calibri is taller than Arial. How can I measure a height of a current font?

Comment: Can you define "height of a font"? Do you mean the [X-height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-height)? the [cap height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_height) the [body height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_height_(typography))? I thnk the only way to do it is visually

Comment: My apologies. I did not know their definitions, but the body height page says "the body height" or "the font (or point) size," so that is what I meant.